# Is parallel, vectorized NORX nearly as fast as hardware-accelerated AES-GCM?

Tags: aes, chacha, norx, keyak

As I understand it, NORX gets 3.5 CPB in an unoptimized implementation.

But NORX can be parallelized.  With 4-way SIMD, I would expect about 7/8 CPB performance.  This is nearly as good as AES-GCM in hardware.

Is something wrong with my assesment, or is parallel NORX a better choice in speed than ChaCha20-Poly1305?  Why were sequential versions the primary recommendations?

I also have the same questions w.r.t. Keyak, which has 1.8 CPB with 2-way parallelism and presumably 0.9 CPB with 4-way parallelism.

Comment: sequential is the primary recommendation for simplicity purposes, and sequential NORX is 2.5 cpb or faster on more modern CPUs

Comment: @RichieFrame still much slower than ChaCha20-Poly1305 (~1.6cpb on Haswell).  But the ChaCha20-Poly1305 implementations are in hand-written assembler, while the NORX optimized implementation is in C with AVX2 intrinsics.